# zypper search also show options for "application" together with "package" and "srcpackage". Can i install that "application".If yes how ?

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

I just upgraded my system to opensuse tumbleweed. Zypper search shows ***Application*** option also together with *package* and *srcpackage* . How to install that application

```
Atif-UG1-2002:~ # zypper se scite
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                | Summary                                                  | Type       
--+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------
  | SciTE Text Editor   | Edit your source files                                   | application
  | scite               | Source Code Editor based on Scintilla                    | srcpackage 
  | scite               | Source Code Editor based on Scintilla                    | package    
  | scite-debuginfo     | Debug information for package scite                      | package    
  | scite-debugsource   | Debug sources for package scite                          | package    
  | texlive-chscite     | Bibliography style for Chalmers University of Technology | package    
  | texlive-chscite-doc | Documentation for texlive-chscite                        | package    
Atif-UG1-2002:~ #
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch -t to specify package types, so the following should work:

```
zypper in -t application "SciTE Text Editor"
```

The zypper-manpage lists the possible types under CONCEPTS -> Package Types